# git clone with ssh url from powershell returns "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." in windows10

Tags: git, powershell, git-bash, ssh-keys

Tried to clone my git repository with ssh url, getting below error

**fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

same if i tried with https url, then i was not able to clone my submodule. because sub module git config has ssh url and i dont have rights to modify it.

created public/private key and same kept in git portal as SSH key. still no success.

**Note:** I was using private repository . I was able to clone my repository successfully with Tortoise git, but facing issue with git bash /  powershell.

can some one can provide solution for above issue.

Comment: [This article](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html) walks you through setting up the correct keys on your windows box to use ssh for clone

Comment: Thanks @Jawad. given article helps to resolve my issue.